# Excluding member by type of first template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I build with VS2013 compiler these member functions:

```
template<typename R, typename ...Args>
fc::variant memberfoo( const std::function<R(Args...)>& f, variants::const_iterator a0, variants::const_iterator e )const
{
    return fc::variant(f(Args...)); // error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'fc::variant'
}

template<typename ...Args>
fc::variant memberfoo(const std::function<void(Args...)>& f, variants::const_iterator a0, variants::const_iterator e)const
{
    f(Args... );
    return fc::variant();
}
```

I think that reason of error is that compiler does not chose member by current template type of parameter "std::function< void(Args...) > &" and in this case he select  first memberfoo.

How to help compiler to chose member by type of std::function< some_function_declaration > ? Or some other tip how to adjust code to be compilable ?

Comment: What are you supposed to pass to the fc::variant constructor? A function or the result of a call?

Comment: By source code of callers it should be result of call.

Comment: `Args...` expands to a list of argument **types**. You need to provide a list of argument **values** for the call. It is nowhere to be found. I have no idea why the first overload is selected, I would need an [mcve] to start looking, but what happens inside both overloads is clearly wrong.